# Find second blank cell after P14 and format its contents as a percentage

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the second blank cell after cell `P14` and format its contents as a percentage. I am presently using this code:

```
Range("P31").NumberFormat = "0%"
```

How can I specify the range so that it finds and formats the second blank row after `P14` as a percentage? The problem occurs because I have data continuously appending a table, which shifts all the data down, and causes the wrong data points to be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I am assuming that you are looking for the next empty cell in the same column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in Col P
        lRow = .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> To check for blank cell after P14
        If lRow < 15 Then Exit Sub

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Range("P14:P" & lRow)

        '~~> Loop through the cell to find the next empty cell
        For Each aCell In rng
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                'Debug.Print aCell.Address
                aCell.NumberFormat = "0%"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

And if I have misunderstood you... i.e you are not looking for the 1st blank cell after P14 but the 2nd blank cell then use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, nCount As Long
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in Col P
        lRow = .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> To check for blank cell after P14
        If lRow < 14 Then Exit Sub

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Range("P14:P" & lRow)

        '~~> Loop through the cell to find the next empty cell
        For Each aCell In rng
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                nCount = nCount + 1

                If nCount = 2 Then
                    Debug.Print aCell.Address
                    aCell.NumberFormat = "0%"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: The second one was what I was looking for. Your method worked perfectly! Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)